# Fabric and Ionic integration

Tags: android, ios, cordova, twitter-fabric

I am trying to use this plugin https://github.com/DrMoriarty/cordova-fabric-crashlytics-plugin

and according to the documentation I need to have the secret and the key

> cordova plugin add
>   https://github.com/vianneyniji/cordova-fabric-crashlytics-plugin
>   --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_SECRET= --variable CRASHLYTICS_API_KEY=

but when I made an account on fabric. It keeps taking me to the https://fabric.io/onboard/pending

so how can I get the key and the secret. i downloaded it into android studio but its still redirecting to this page.

Any ideas on how to move past it ?

Answer (score 1):

Crushlytics is now part of Fabric, you do not need third party plugins for this. Use the official plugin at `https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin`

On the [install notes](https://github.com/sarriaroman/FabricPlugin#install) I tells you to get the key from [this url](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install):

> Note: If you have never registered an app with your organization, the organization page may redirect you to a wizard preventing you from obtaining your keys. You may be able to obtain your keys from [this page](https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install). Scroll down to the "Run Script Build Phase" block. The first, shorter string is the API key and the second, longer string is the build secret. If that doesn't work you
>       can follow the wizard and integrate the kit into a dummy "Hello World" 
>       project which should then unlock the organization page.

Answer (score 0):

According to the README of another Fabric plugin you can go to https://fabric.io/kits/ios/crashlytics/install. Scroll down to the "Run Script Build Phase" block. The first, shorter string is the API key and the second, longer string is the build secret.

See https://github.com/etabard/cordova-fabric-crashlytics-plugin